# Is it normal for integration to be a slow process?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, integration-by-parts

I have currently been doing integration problems, and it seems to me that I am quite slow at the process.

I was wondering whether that was normal or am I using inefficient methods to get to my final solution?

For example integrating: $\frac{x}{e^{x}}$ takes me about 10 to 12 minutes.
I use a combination of integration by parts and integration by substitution to get my answer.

**This is my working out process:**

$u = x$

$du = 1 dx $

$v = -e^{-x}$  (Used integration by substitution)

$dv = e^{-x}  dx$

Integration by Parts form:
$uv - \int u \, du$

$-xe^{-x} - \int-e^{-x}  dx$

** For the integration section I used Integration by parts.

**Final Answer:**

$(-e^{-x})(x+1)+C$

Comment: Why do you have $u=e^{x}$, $du=1dx$? Also, is the original integral $\frac{x}{e^{x}}$ or $\frac{x}{e^{-x}}=xe^{x}$?

Comment: Not following your calculation.  Did you mean to start with $u=x$? And is the integrand really $\frac x{e^{-x}}$?  In any case, I wouldn't worry about the speed.  Better to do it carefully and correctly at first.  I'd also recommend checking your answer by differentiating it.  As you work more and more examples, your speed will increase.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $du=e^xdx$ to start with ? And are you integrating $x/e^{-x}$ or $xe^{-x}$ ?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I accidently stated u= e^(-x), but have since fixed it.

Comment: Do not despair! It might seem like there are a lot of things to keep track of, but the bag of tricks is very small. The methods you've been taught are very limited, in that it's unreasonable to expect that a closed form for the anti-derivative (in terms of elementary functions) will exist for a particular function. You will get faster, but I don't think one's ability to speed-solve integrals is so important, although such computations can at times be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would express $du$ and $dv$ if you were to compute e.g. $\int \sin^2(x)\cos(x)dx$. You could say $u=\sin(x)$, that is implicitly $u(x)=\sin(x)$. Then you have $u'(x)=\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$, or $du/dx=\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$. That way, you can rearrange to $dx=du/\cos(x)$. And $\int \sin^2(x)\cos(x)dx = \int u^2\cos(x)\frac{du}{\cos(x)}= \int u^2du$ and there you go.
If you're just looking for ANY antiderivative, no worries about the boundaries changing on the integral. Otherwise that needs your attention too.

This is an example, this integral is actually easier when noticing that you have $(f\circ g)'(x)$ inside it with $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}$ and $g(x)=\sin(x)$

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem : when assigning $u$ and $v$ in preperation for integration by parts, you are not using variable substitution. There's no need here to express $du$ and $dv$ in terms of $dx$. I'm not saying you can never use both methods but I think you got them confused here, didn't you ?

Assuming you were integrating $xe^{-x}$, a sensible choice would be $u(x)=x$ and $v'(x)=e^{-x}$, because your integral is now written as $\int u(x)v'(x)dx$, hence when using the $[u(x)v(x)]-\int u'(x)v(x)dx$ formula this integral is easy to calculate as $u'(x)=1$.

If I was right about your confusion, then it's probably due to common but incorrect use of notations. When integrating by parts, you are merely rewriting the integral without changing the integrated domain nor the integrated function.  You are just spotting a clever product inside the integral to be computed, and rewriting it for visual comfort when applying the formula. Like you might write $u=x^2$ and $v=\sin(x)$ to apply the $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$ formula to $x^2\sin(x)$

Comment: Writing dv and du in terms of dx for integration by parts is fairly common.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how else would I write du and dv , if not in terms of x?

Comment: I don't see how that could be of help here, but since $v'(x)=e^{-x}$, rewrinting this gives you $dv/dx=e^{-x}$ or equivalently, $dv/dx=-v$. You can then rearrange them as you wish using standard algebra.